# Sorting of ArrayList<Track>

Tags: java, list, sorting, arraylist, collections

I want to sort ArrayList according to artist's name I have used comparator interface but I'm not able to sort the list. So kindly help me to solve the problem. The track data will be read from a file Trackdump. The file would contain one track data per line in the format TITLE/ARTIST/RATING/BPM

Here is the code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class MusicLibrary {

    ArrayList<Track> songList = new ArrayList<Track>();

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        new MusicLibrary().go();

    }

    public void go() {
                 System.out.println("go");
        getTracks();
        System.out.println("Before Sorting:");
        System.out.println(songList);
        Collections.sort(songList);
        System.out.println("Sorted according to Artist's name:");
        System.out.println(songList);
    }

    void getTracks() {
                  System.out.println("gt");
        File file = new File("TrackDump.txt");
        try{
        BufferedReader readr = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));


        String line = null;
                System.out.println(readr);
        while ((line = readr.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
            addSong(line);
        }
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    void addSong(String lineToParse) {
        String[] tokens = lineToParse.split("/");
        Track nextSong = new Track(tokens[0], tokens[1], tokens[2], tokens[3]);
        songList.add(nextSong);
        System.out.println(songList);
    }

}


class Track implements Comparator<Track>
{
    String title;
    String artist;
    String rating;
    String bpm;
    public int compare(Track o1, Track o2) {
        return o1.getArtist().compareTo(o2.getArtist());
    }
    public Track(String a, String t, String r, String b) {
        title = t;
        artist = a;
        rating = r;
        bpm = b;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object aSong) {
        return this.equals(aSong);
    }


    public String getArtist() {
        return artist;
    }

    public String getBpm() {
        return bpm;
    }

    public String getRating() {
        return rating;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return title + "-" + artist;
    }
}
```

Trackdump:

```
Title1/Artist1/8/320
Title2/Artist2/10/48
T5/A7/10/120
Title4/A7/9/240
T7/Artist5/7/320
Title6/Artist6/3/240
T9/A7/1/550
T6/Artist8/5/120
T1/Artist9/5/290
Song2/A0/5/320
Song5/A8/10/320
Song1/A2/6/290
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to implement the `Comparable` interface and then you can use `Collections.sort()`.

```
class Track implements Comparable<Track> {

    String title;
    String artist;
    String rating;
    String bpm;

    @Override
    public int compare(Track other) {
        return this.getArtist().compareTo(other.getArtist());
    }

    ...
```

In theory it would work too when implementing `Comparator` but then you have to pass a `Track` object into `Collections.sort()` to act as the `Comparator`. But that is a rather weird way of doing it so better use the solution above.

```
Collections.sort(songList, new Track(null, null, null, null));
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to implement `Comparable` class to your `Track` class. Not `Comparator`. Then override `compareTo()` method. It would look like this:

```
public class Track implements Comparable<Track> {

   // Variables, constructor, getters, setters ...

   @Override
   public int compareTo(Track other) {
      return this.getArtist().compareTo(other.getArtist());
   }
}
```

Finally sort with  `Collections.sort();`